# HaxePunk - When running neko/windows and hovering mouse over window error is prompted

Tags: flash, haxe, flashdevelop, openfl, haxepunk

I've been trying to build my project to windows/neko but I keep getting this strange error whenever I hover my mouse over the game window:

> Invalid field access Called from com.haxepunk.utils.Input::onTouchMove
>   line 577 Called from
>   openfl._legacy.events.EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent line 98 Called
>   from openfl._legacy.display.DisplayObject::__dispatchEvent line 182
>   Called from openfl._legacy.display.DisplayObject::__fireEvent line 244
>   Called from openfl._legacy.display.Stage::__onTouch line 1048 Called
>   from openfl._legacy.display.Stage::__doProcessStageEvent line 465

I've tried reinstalling everything from flashdevelop to haxepunk and to openfl but I keep on getting this error. If you know a fix I'll gladly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: What version of HaxePunk and openfl are you using?